# Appending button to <li> tag with DOM/JS but not sure how to display correctly with Flexbox / CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, dom, flexbox, css-grid

I'm learning CSS, but unable to get desired layout using Flexbox and CSS Grid on attached buttons.

I'm practising both Flexbox and CSS Grid at same time. Issue is if the HTML document has button tags already included, the CSS works fine. However CSS is not working on buttons appended to `li` tag using Javascript/dom. Same issues happening with both Flexbox and CSS grid.

```
// original HTML file used
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
        <li>Jello</li>
        <li>Spinach</li>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Birthday Cake</li>
        <li>Candles</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

The result I'm trying to get is the delete button at the end of the `li` item (similar to first 2 items, notebook and jello) so that it's all justified at right side.
Any new items entered into list does not display as intended as well.   Please take a look at attached link below. Any comments appreciated.

https://jsbin.com/febulokoru/edit?html,css,output

```
EDIT1: took a look at console again, realised the button was being appended to the textContent(inside the closing li tag). How do I move it out of li and append it after closing li tag?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nested grid can be used to fix layout issue.
instead of appendChild, use insertAdjacentElement method so button is not inside of `li` tag